# Define what gets shown on "New Tab" in Firefox 22

Tags: firefox, bloatware

Some crapware has installed itself into my system and has "infected" all my browsers. I've been able to reset all the home pages and search providers to what I want - but in Firefox (v22), I'm still struggling with one point:

whenever I open a new tab, that crapware site gets loaded - which I **DO NOT** want. But how and where can I undo this damage? I haven't found anything just yet....

I did find a number of items on the Mozilla support site talking about the `about:newtab` page - but that's not what seems to be causing this site to load in every single new tab that I'm opening.

Where else in Firefox can I define what site gets loaded on a new tab? I gone back and forth through all the configuration dialogs, checked the extensions etc - it's not there. I've removed all mentions of that crap site from my registry - so it shouldn't be there, either.

Where else could that crap URL be hiding and be pulled from for each new tab??

Comment: Do you know what the crapware that installed itself was? And what is the website that gets loaded?

Comment: Yes - it was a German CD-/DVD-burner called `Free Disc Burner` and that URL it sends me to is a lame search site, `http://www.delta-search.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :-)

In Firefox, go to `about:config`.

There's a setting called

```
 browser.newtab.url
```

Whatever you have set in there is displayed when a new tab is opened without a specific URL. It default to `about:newtab` which shows the most recent sites - but this crapware re-routed that URL to their lame search site.

Fixed it, and things are now back to normal and Firefox is usable again!